# Is the cylinder an algebraic variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

$$
\cases {
x^2 + y^2 = 1 \\
z = z
}
$$
where the 2nd equation can be regarded as $\varnothing$.

Is this an algebraic variety?

If yes, is the surface defined by the intersection of 2 (perpendicular) cylinders also an algebraic variety?

Thanks.

Comment: $V(x^2 + y^2 - r^2) \subset \mathbb A^3$ is the infinite cylinder.  Are you wanting a cylinder with finite height?

Comment: No, I just thought that a cylinder is kinda weird as an algebraic variety.

Comment: The infinite cylinder is a real algebraic variety. Real algebraic geometry has quite a different flavor from algebraic geometry over algebraically closed fields such as $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan:  so, if the field is $\mathbb{C}$ then the cylinder won't be a variety?

Comment: It seems that $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ is not expressible as a complex polynomial equation in terms of $z = x + yi$.

Comment: Also the cylinder is a 3D object so it cannot be of complex dimension $n \in \mathbb{N}$.  So it can only be defined as a real algebraic variety...

Comment: But I guess we can also have "complex cylindrification", ie, cylinders of complex dimension $n+1$, where the extra dimension is "free"?

Answer (score 1):

$V(x^2+y^2-1, x^2 + z^2 - 1) = \{(x,y,z) \in k \mid x^2 + y^2 = 1 \wedge x^2 + z^2 = 1\}$ is the set of points defined by the intersection of two perpendicular cylinders. So is $W(x^2+y^2-1, y^2 + z^2 - 1)$.